# why is the first column of my PCA always the largest?

Tags: pca, covariance

I have a set of samples, compute the covariance matrix, and calculate the eigenvalues. The largest eigenvalue corresponds to the first column.

I then re-order my original samples and repeat the process. The largest eigenvalue still corresponds to the first column. What am I doing wrong?

I have a simple example to demonstrate:

```
import numpy as np

x = list(range(0, 10))
y = list(map(lambda val : 5 * val, x))
z = list(map(lambda val : 2 * val, x))
xyz = np.array([x, y, z]).reshape(10, 3)
zxy = np.array([z, x, y]).reshape(10, 3)
yzx = np.array([y, z, x]).reshape(10, 3)

e1, _ = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(xyz.T))
e2, _ = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(zxy.T))
e3, _ = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(yzx.T))


# after printing e1 and e2:
# e1 = [359.20992236   5.39279005 102.79728759]
# e2 = [432.00432176  29.85486618   5.54081206]
# e3 = [286.51923526 159.85319056  21.02757418]
```

This experiment tells me that the feature importance is dependent on the position of the column in the matrix, which doesn't make sense. If a column was responsible for most of the variance in a data set, then I would expect that column of the covariance matrix to have the largest value, regardless of how the columns in the data set were ordered.

Comment: Eigenvalues don't tell you the importance of columns in the covariance matrix. They tell you the importance of the eigenvectors into which that covariance matrix can be decomposed. When computing eigenvectors, most software packages will by default sort them in order of decreasing eigenvalues, s.t. the most important eigenvectors will be the first columns in the matrix of eigenvectors.

Comment: I just wanted to say that vectorizing your code would make it faster and more readable: `x= np.arange(0, 10); y= x*5; z= x*2`.

Comment: Ruben, that makes sense. Carlo, thanks for the feedback. Perhaps what I need to do is sum the columns of the covariance matrix.